# Book to read before "introduction to gauge field theory" by Bailin and Love

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, education

A teacher has recommended me to read this book in order to prepare for a project I am doing. Anyway, I feel that I should need a book in order to prepare for this one. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11878/2451