# Looking for a self-contained book on QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, education

I am looking for an introductory book on QFT which is relatively **self-contained**.

Aims:

Useful for philosophers interested in Philosophy of Science (but Mostly math-oriented)

If such a book simply does not exist, I would equally appreciate multiple books that answers the question.

Shankar's QM book does what I intend but for QM. Perhaps a book like Shankar's would be perfect.

Comment: Aware of [Folland's tourist guide](https://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Theory-Mathematical-Surveys-Monographs/dp/0821847058/ref=sr_1_4?dchild=1&keywords=quantum+field+theory+for+mathematicians&qid=1611869285&sr=8-4)?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8441/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11878/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

Jakob Schwichtenberg has written a book called [No-Nonsense Quantum Field Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3948763011). While I haven't read this one, I've read other books by the same author in the same series and they're great.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a philosophy of science approach, Weinberg's *The Quantum Theory of Fields* is a classic textbook that examines why QTF is the way it is. It builds up the theory from fundamental ideas. It also has a chapter on the history of the field. It is pretty mathematically advanced though, so it might not be the best introduction.

Comment: Weinbergs books are masterpices **but** they surely are not a good introductory books. The notation is complicated, to say the least, and the formalism it's difficult to digest without prior knowledge of the subject. But the historical chapters are indeed very cool and should be read whenever possible.