# Quantum Field Theory book for learning just the fundamental laws

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, education

All the books that I've found focus too much on practical calculation techniques and experiments. But that's not what I want to learn the theory for. I'm learning it only as a hobby and I am primarily only interested in the most fundamental math. Is there a book for someone like me?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8441/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11878/2451 and links therein. Please note that res. recom. qs are restricted on Phys.SE.

Comment: A book that it is not too technical but rather focuses on ideas is the book by Zee "quantum field theory in a nutshell"... But if you really want to learn qft you will no be able to avoid learning also technical details at some point...