# MS bar renormalization scheme

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, renormalization

Kindly suggest any reference or book in which I can grasp the idea of the MS bar renormalization scheme, and it will be beneficial if it shows some mathematical rigor.

Comment: P&S maybe?? Or Srednicki's book perhaps

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8441/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11878/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the books of Peskin and Schroeder and Srednicki already suggested, you may want to look at "Quantum Field Theory and The Standard Model", by Matthew D. Schwartz. It is a well-written book with tons of examples and explicit computations, so that you can see for yourself how renormalization (and other things) work. Also (though a little more advanced) there is "QCD for the practitioner" by Pascual and Tarrach.

And regarding mathematical rigor, I can tell you the mathematics of regularization and renormalization rely on advanced mathematical strategies such as analytic continuation and are not usually discussed in Physics books.