# Learning QFT from scratch

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, education

I'm a final-year physics degree student and I want to know about QFT, but my knowledge about tensor mathematics and groups of symmetries is really low, as my university doesn't offer us advanced mathematical subjects.

So, would you please suggest me some books or any other resource that make it clear and easy to understand these mathematical basics and that digs into QFT?

Comment: I am also learning QFT for the first time at the moment. I feel standard texts like Peskin are quite nice. I would recommend Sidney Coleman's lecture notes though - I found them quite clear and lucid with a decent level of formalism. Weinberg's text would be the mathematically more rigorous one though.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8441/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11878/2451 and links therein.